# Hibernate 4 Delete from HT_tables where IN clause Token unknown ","

Tags: hibernate, firebird, jaybird

Using Hibernate 4, the below generated query failed:

```
delete from ErpEmploye_AUD where (code, folder_codeId, REV) 
    IN 
(select code, folder_codeId, REV from HT_ErpEmploye_AUD where hib_sess_id=1)
```

Firebird exception:

```
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 39
,
```

In the `org.hibernate.hql.spi.TableBasedDeleteHandlerImpl` class there is
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/hql/spi/TableBasedDeleteHandlerImpl.java

```
private String generateDelete(String tableName, String[] columnNames, 
                String idSubselect, String comment) {
    final Delete delete = new Delete()
        .setTableName( tableName )
        .setWhere( "(" + StringHelper.join( ", ", columnNames ) +
```

") IN (" + idSubselect + ")" );
return delete.toStatementString();
}

So I want to adapt the code to Firebird, what is the nearest Firebird syntax to do the same job?

I just migrated to Hibernate 4, and it appears that every delete from the temporary tables added in Hibernate 4 (prefixed with HT_ ...) is based on this method, so it looks as an important issue.

Comment: I don't think Firebird supports that syntax. Looks like a Hibernate bug (assuming you are using the correct database dialect for Firebird)

Comment: this should be reported to hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the nearest Firebird syntax is

```
delete from ErpEmploye_AUD e where 
exists( select code, folder_codeId, REV from HT_ErpEmploye_AUD ht
 where ( hib_sess_id=1 and e.code=ht.code and e.folder_codeId=ht.folder_codeId and e.REV=ht.REV ))
```

Second the right Hibernate generateDelete code:

```
private String generateDelete(String tableName, String[] columnNames, String idSubselect, String comment) {
    String[] columnEquals = new String[columnNames.length];
    for (int i=0;i<columnNames.length;i++){
        columnEquals[i] = "tr."+columnNames[i]+"=ht."+columnNames[i];
    }
    if (idSubselect.contains("where"))
        idSubselect = idSubselect.replace("where", "ht where");
    else
        idSubselect = idSubselect + " ht where";
    final Delete delete = new Delete()
            .setTableName( tableName+" tr " )
            //.setWhere( "(" + StringHelper.join( ", ", columnNames ) + ") IN (" + idSubselect + ")" );
            .setWhere( "exists("+ idSubselect +" "+ StringHelper.join( " and ", columnEquals ) + ")" );     
    
    if ( factory().getSettings().isCommentsEnabled() ) {
        delete.setComment( comment );
    }
    return delete.toStatementString();
}
```

I hope that this should be generalised in Hibernate, because this is not a standard code, or could be supported by Firebird